# Set focus to textbox jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to set the focus to a textbox when a button is clicked, so the html is:

```
<input id="commentName" name="commentName" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

And what I've tried is :

```
    $('#commentName').focus();
    $('#commentName:text:visible:first').focus();
    $('input[name=commentName]').focus();
```

but none of these are actually putting the cursor in the box. Any chance that someone could assist please?

The jQuery version is 3.2.1

Thanks,
C

Comment: Where is the code of your click event ? and are you sure that your click event is perfectly done ?

Comment: Your code seems ok. I've ran it locally and it focuses with just the first line. Are there any errors in the dev tools window? Put a debugger statement before the focus and ensure its being hit.

Comment: They all work fine; assuming you are running the code at the correct time: https://jsfiddle.net/ra0uud60/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/585bhwm2/

Comment: Hi, yes I can see that the event is firing: 
$('#commentList').on('click', '.replyButton', showCommentBox);
function showCommentBox(e) { alert('started'; $('#commentName').focus(); alert('Finished'); }

I'm getting both of the alerts and I don't receive again console errors just not happening!

Comment: Just follow the @JohnR fiddle, it works very well

Comment: What browser are you using? Some browsers don't put the cursor **inside** the box, they just highlight the control.

Comment: It's the latest version of Chrome

Comment: It all seems to be running fine just not working

Comment: Please create an [MCVE] showing the problem and add it to your question.

Comment: I do apologise, I've thought that I'd respond to this yesterday. You're right $('#commentName').focus(); does actually work I think that I had an error elsewhere in my scripting block which was stopping this function running.
All is well in the world. Thank you for your time :)